# How to let SQL Server 2012's database be imported to SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008 how to import SQL Server 2012's database?

Comment: Use SSMS to script the database at the 2005 compatibility level, SSIS to import the data, replication. Did you even Google this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't Restore from newer versions. But you can script the original database (schema and data), and run the scripts in the target database. Make sure you script using the correct compatibility level.

See my [step-by-step description](http://devio.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/restoring-a-sql-server-database-backup-created-by-a-newer-version-of-sql-server/) on my blog.

Comment: It should be noted that while technically this works and it (and versions of it) are the only effective way to do it, for any complex or extensively developed database, this is no trivial thing.  I generally tell my customers that it is a 2-5 day job and will require extensive applications testing to validate that it worked correctly.